# Instantiating Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script that is supposed to spawn an enemy every 1 second. However, after one second it spawns hundreds and doesn't stop.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform spawny;
    public Transform p;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine("Spawn");
    }
    public IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Instantiate(spawny, p.position, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: because you  run it every frame

Comment: According to @BugFinder just put `StartCoroutine(Spawn())` into your `Start` method.

Comment: @Kluddizz that wont do it every second but putting it in update means it will after 1 second spawn one for every frame.. and keep going..

Comment: @BugFinder You are true, but I've never said anything against that.

Comment: You may be interested in [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop in your `Spawn` coroutine, and start it in `Start` so that there is only ever one instance of it running:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform spawny;
    public Transform p;
    public bool doSpawn;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        doSpawn = true;
        StartCoroutine("Spawn");
    }

    public IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(1);

        while (doSpawn)
        {
            yield return wait;
            Instantiate(spawny, p.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I implement your code, I get this error:

Assets\Scripts\PSpawner.cs(20,28): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.WaitForSeconds' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'

The error doesn't allow me to start or test the project.

Comment: @george thanks for the comment. Try `WaitForSeconds wait ...` instead please